# Mongodb schema to building an appointment booking system

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, scheduler, scheduling

We have two different approaches for an appointment scheduling system, using mongodb.

## 1st approach:

```
appointments:
    {
        resourceId: "string",
        resourceType: "doc"/"nut"...,
        userId: "string",
        userName: "string",
        startDate: "2020-05-18T16:00:00Z",
        endDate: 2020-05-18T17:00:00Z
        title: "string",
        description: "string",
        type: "string"/"off"
    },
    {
        resourceId: "string",
        resourceType: "doc"/"nut"...,
        userId: "string",
        userName: "string",
        startDate: "2020-05-21T12:00:00Z",
        endDate: 2020-05-21T12:30:00Z,
        title: "string",
        description: "string",
        type: "string"/"off"
    },
    ...

resources:
    {
        resourceId: "string",
        resourceName: "string"
        resourceType: "doc"/"nut"/"room",
        autoApprove: true/false,
        constantDaysOff: [sunnday]
    },
    {
        resourceId: "string",
        resourceName: "string"
        resourceType: "doc"/"nut"/"room",
        autoApprove: true/false,
        constantDaysOff: [sunnday]
    },
    {
        resourceId: "string",
        resourceName: "string"
        resourceType: "doc"/"nut"/"room",
        autoApprove: true/false,
        constantDaysOff: [sunnday]
    }
```

Here `appointments` and `resources` are different collections, with sample documents in each collection.

## 2nd approach:

```
resources:
    {
        resourceId: "string",
        resourceName: "string",
        resourceType: "doc"/"nut"...,
        constantDaysOff: [sunday],
        2020-05-21: [
            {
                startDate: "2020-05-21T12:00:00Z",
                endDate: 2020-05-21T12:30:00Z,
                userId: "string",
                userName: "string",
                title: "string",
                description: "string",
                type: "string"/"off"
            }, 
            {
                startDate: "2020-05-21T14:00:00Z",
                endDate: 2020-05-21T14:30:00Z,
                userId: "string",
                userName: "string",
                title: "string",
                description: "string",
                type: "string"/"off"
            }
        ],
        2020-05-22: [
            {
                startDate: "2020-05-22T12:00:00Z",
                endDate: 2020-05-22T12:30:00Z,
                userId: "string",
                userName: "string",
                title: "string",
                description: "string",
                type: "string"/"off"
            }, 
            {
                startDate: "2020-05-22T14:00:00Z",
                endDate: 2020-05-22T14:30:00Z,
                userId: "string",
                userName: "string",
                title: "string",
                description: "string",
                type: "string"/"off"
            }
        ]
        ...
    }
```

Here we only have one collection, and appointment dates are keys in the collection. Each date key would contain multiple json objects representing different appointments on the same day.

### NOTE:

There are no appointments longer than 1 day, the reason we have `startDate` and `endDate` is to calculate the length of the appointment, its start and end time.

We need to be able to perform queries, most efficiently, along the lines of:

- get all appointments for a specific resource id
- get appointments for a resource between two different dates
- get appointments for a user between different dates
- cancel/remove appointments

A resource could be anything, for example a doctor, coach, room...

So my question is which one would be more efficient/feasible when it comes to mongodb queries?

Comment: The second would be more efficient and easier to handle since you can get the arrays by their keys. We've been building kinda the exact the same app as you try, but we abandoned it. Here is the [frontend](https://github.com/natixco/booking-app-old-frontend) and the [backend](https://github.com/KDani-99/booking-app-old-backend) repo for it. You might find helpful snippets there.

Comment: don't you think that it'll be ugly to query by `userId` in the 2nd approach? @Natixco

Comment: I'm not a backend guy, but it doesn't matter that much. Either way you have to query by date and then by userId or vica versa.

Answer (score 0):

1. most articles said not to use start-Date and end-Date, but Date and start/end-Time (not even in Date format) - you mostly select (query) by day/days, then you will handle time

Time is more flexible, especially when you need some time-step between appointments. Also, you can easily edit the time long without changing the date or change the date without changing the time.

2. IMHO: according to the previous point, it's much better to use your first variant and the second one I dislike.

In the second variant, it will be hard to change the date. You will need to handle the whole array, upsert by date, and then upsert the whole Set of those.